# How to find the id of the html while looping through <tr> in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a queue management page where we have multiple Html tables on a single page and each table holds 10 values including name and image, now I wanna remove a row from the table when the present button is pressed and I did it using this following code

```
function removePresent() {
               
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const HallNo = urlParams.get('hallno');
    const TvIP = urlParams.get('tvip');

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("PresentDisplayRemover")',
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'HallNo': HallNo, 'TvIP': TvIP },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {

            $.each(response, function (j, e) {
                const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('TD'));
            $.each(rows, function (i) {
                if ($(rows[i]).text() === e.StudentId) {
                    $(rows[i]).parent().remove();
                }
            });
        }
   });
}
```

Now my flow also requires me to find the Id of the matched  to increment a counter, I have no idea how to do it and I also tried searching online but I ended up finding nothing,I'm relatively new to js and jquery since my main workflow only consists of me working with .NET so any help would be great, Thank You.

Comment: Does `$(rows[i]).parent().id` work?

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets no its returned as undefined

Comment: @Ashwin You can give a try with it $(rows[i]).parent().attr("id");

Comment: @AtmiyaKolsawala hello i also tried that but it returns undefined

Comment: There are some errors with your closing braces

Comment: @BobVandevliet sorry about that, its from copy paste but its fine in ide

Comment: did you try something like this on the button event `$(this).parent().remove()`

Comment: No worries, I just noticed. Unfortunately I don't see why `.attr('id')` wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you trace back, maybe something else is going wrong earlier in your code, try `console.log($(rows[i]).parent())` to validate if `.parent()` works as expected, etc.